# How to add labels to t-SNE in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, machine-learning

I'm using t-SNE to searching for relations on a dataset which have seven features.

[image]

I'm using a dictionary to assing colors to the `y` labels on the plot:

```
encoding = {'d0': 0, 'd1': 1, 'd2': 2, 'd3': 3, 'd4': 4, 'd5': 5, 'd6': 6, 'd7': 7}

plt.scatter(X_tsne[:, 0], X_tsne[:, 1], c=y['label'].apply(lambda x: city_encoding[x]))
plt.show()
```

The problem here is that is not clear which color corresponds to which label. The dataset actually has over 100 labels, so it's not something I'd like to handle manually.

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can plot each category separately on the same axes, and let Matplotlib generate the colors and legend:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

groups = pd.DataFrame(X_tsne, columns=['x', 'y']).assign(category=y).groupby('category')
for name, points in groups:
    ax.scatter(points.x, points.y, label=name)

ax.legend()
```

For randomly generated `X`, this gives

[image]